# java - intellij - getClassLoader()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classloader

I have problems with class loader:
This is my main class (junit test):

```
package com.blabla.project

Url url = new Temp().getLoader("myFile.xml");
```

my util class:

```
package com.blabla.project.util

public class Temp{
   Public URL getLoader(String path)ֽֽ‏{
  return this.getClass().getResource(path);
}}
```

I tryed everything, with this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
with ("/myFile.xml"), ("./myFile.xml"), placed the file under package project, under util, under root. No combination works
I always get NullPointerException
Where is my mistake? Could it have anything to do with Intellij?

Comment: Where is `myFile.xml`?

Comment: I tryed to place it under package com.blabla.project.util, and under package com.blabla.project. same as main and Temp. both failed.

Comment: IIRC, IntelliJ may not copy non-Java files from `src/main/java` by default.  You should put your resource files (e.g. .xml files) under `src/main/resources`.

Comment: It would be good if you answered your own question, then, later, marked it as right. Then this question won't show up in the unanswered list.